# Visualization showing count of items common to two buckets in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have data that has the following fields:

```
options: version=1.6.0, md5: 123456, matched= yes
```

or

```
options: version=1.7.0, md5: 123456, matched= no
```

How can I create a a visualization that shows count of matched entries by version limited to where md5 matches?

I am using Kibana 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have a `data table` as your visualization. Then go on select your aggregation as `count`. Then you could add `buckets`, where you can write a `filter` according to your needs.

So in your case you could have a filter, which could look like:

```
version=1.7.0 AND matched= yes
```

You could do this to your other version as well. Have a look at [Data table](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.0/data-table.html#data-table).